# What is a 255b Word™?

Tags: steganography, computer-puzzle, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **255b Word™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{2.5}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ 255b }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[grey]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  AMBIGUOUSLY }&\text{ AMBITIOUSLY }\\ \hline
\text{  BOXING }&\text{ BOXER }\\ \hline
\text{  COMPLICATE }&\text{ COMPLEX }\\ \hline
\text{  DECENTRALIZE }&\text{ DECENTRALIZATION }\\ \hline
\text{  ENTERTAINMENT }&\text{ EXCITEMENT }\\ \hline
\text{  FINALLY }&\text{ FINISHED }\\ \hline
\text{  GEOGRAPHY }&\text{ GEOLOGY }\\ \hline
\text{  HENRY }&\text{ HIGUAIN }\\ \hline
\text{  INDICATION }&\text{ INCLINATION }\\ \hline
\text{  JUXTAPOSING }&\text{ JUXTAPOSITION }\\ \hline
\text{  KNOWLEDGE }&\text{ KNOWLEDGEABLE }\\ \hline
\text{  LIGHTNING }&\text{ LIGHTENING }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
255b Words™,Not 255b Words™
AMBIGUOUSLY,AMBITIOUSLY
BOXING,BOXER
COMPLICATE,COMPlEX
DECENTRALIZE,DECENTHALIZATION
ENTERTAINMENT,EXCITEMENT
FINALLY,FINISHEO
GEOGRAPHY,GEOLORY
HENRY,HIGUAIN
INDICATION,INCLINATION
JUXTAPOSING,JUXTAPOSITION
KNOWLEDGE,KNOWLEDgEABLE
LIGHTNING,LIGHTENING
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a 255b Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of 255b Words™; many more exist.

**Problem: What is a 255b Word™? And why is the property called 255b?**

---

**Hint:**

> This rule is actually quite arbitrary. I don't think you can read my mind without the [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography) tag.

Comment: Is the CSV misspelled? ("DECENT'H'ALIZATION" with 'H' in CSV, but with 'R'  in the table) Is CSV purposely not fully capitalized? (such as 'g' in "KNOWLED'g'EABLE" and 'l' in "COMP'l'EX")

Comment: @Vepir Yeah, I deliberately misspelled a few letters in CSV. :)

Comment: are both lists correct?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, both are correct.